# Is $\operatorname{tr}|A|=\operatorname{tr}|A^\dagger|$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Is it true that $\operatorname{tr}|A|=\operatorname{tr}|A^\dagger|$ for any operator in a Hilbert space? I can prove this statement for normal operators such that $[A,A^\dagger]=0$. I want to know is there any proof or counter example for general case?

Comment: What does the vertical line mean? Do they mean just the trace or something else?

Comment: @Dog_69 $|A|=\sqrt{A A^{\dagger}}$

Comment: Then, if you space is not finite dimensional I would say not, because in general $A^{\dagger\dagger}\neq A$.

Comment: @Dog_69 Well at least for bounded operators, the ${}^\dagger$ map is an involution, i.e. $A^{\dagger\dagger}=A$. For unbounded operators, this is a whole different thing involving possible domain problems etc. - then again, I personally would rather not tackle the above question for unbounded operators for various reasons.

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* Any references to theorems etc. I will make in the following are with respect to the book *"Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics. I: Functional Analysis"* by Reed & Simon (1980).

If your Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ is separable and $A\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$, i.e. $A$ is a bounded operator on $\mathcal H$, your assertion is indeed true for the following reason. As you might know, on separable Hilbert spaces one defines the trace class to be
$$
\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H):=\lbrace A\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\,|\,\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})<\infty\rbrace\,.
$$
Here one uses that on positive semi-definite operators, the trace is well-defined (independent of the chosen orthonormal basis), linear and takes values in $[0,\infty]$. Now if $A\in\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ then $A$ is compact *(Theorem VI.21)* which is equivalent to admitting a singular value decomposition
$$
A=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma_n(A)\langle \psi_n,\cdot\rangle\phi_n\tag{1}
$$
with unique non-negative numbers $(\sigma_n(A))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and orthonormal systems $(\psi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal H$ where the sum converges in the operator norm *(Theorem VI.17)*. Due to the above singular value decompoition, it is evident that every compact operator $A$ on $\mathcal H$ satisfies
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma_n(A)\,,\tag{2}
$$
where the right-hand side (and thus both sides) might take the value $\infty$. This is enough preparation to prove the statement in question.

> **Proposition.** Let $A\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})=\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A A^\dagger})$, where one side (and thus both sides) might take the value $\infty$.

*Proof.* We may assume that at either $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})$ or $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A A^\dagger})$ (or both) are finite - otherwise we would obviously be done due to $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})=\infty=\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A A^\dagger})$. W.l.o.g. $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})<\infty$ so $A\in\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma_n(A)$. By (1), obviously $A^\dagger$ is compact as well with $\sigma_n(A^\dagger)=(\sigma_n(A))^*=\sigma_n(A)$ and thus
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma_n(A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma_n(A^\dagger)=\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{A A^\dagger})<\infty
$$
which concludes the proof. $\quad\square$